# Get images from DrawingGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, drawing

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I have some problems with finding the proper answer:S

How to get frames as `Bitmap`'s or `Image`'s (or something similar) from `DrawingGroup`? I don't actually know how to bite it. I tried to look for it in the Internet, but had problems with finding something useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an image to be used as the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) of an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control, you could simply put the drawing into a [DrawingImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage.aspx):

```
var drawing = ...
var drawingImage = new DrawingImage(drawing);
image.Source = drawingImage;
```

If the question is about creating a [BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) (i.e. something that can be encoded by a [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) via a [BitmapFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe.aspx)), there is no direct conversion. You have to put the image into an intermediate Image control and render that control into a [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx), which is a BitmapSource:

```
var drawing = ...
var drawingImage = new DrawingImage(drawing);
var image = new Image { Source = drawingImage };
var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(100, 100, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
image.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
bitmap.Render(image);
```