# WPF Cannot scroll an image inside a ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, scrollviewer

I try to display an image in my window :

```
<Window x:Class="Problem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <Image Source="cat.jpg" Stretch="Uniform">
                    <Image.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                    </Image.LayoutTransform>
                </Image>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

where cat.jpg is a 1920x1080 image.

Here is the result :

[image]

As you can see, the VerticalScrollbar is disabled although I can't see the full cat head. Moreover, HorisontalScrollBar is Invisible.

My question is : How to enable scrollbar in order to scroll over my image ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `StackPanel`. It gives its content infinite space, so the `ScrollViewer` has the height of the image. If you need to stack something under the image, create a `StackPanel` inside the `ScrollViewer`:

```
<Window x:Class="Problem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="cat.jpg" Stretch="Uniform">
                <Image.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                </Image.LayoutTransform>
            </Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: In my real code, I need to stack a ButtonBar under my image

Comment: Then you should move the StackPanel inside the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Thanks for answered :) The problem with the stackpanel inside the scrollviewer is that the button is not alway visible. I would like it to show up under the scrollviewer. I cannot use DockPanel.Dock.Bottom because  I already have one.

Comment: @Epitouille You can dock multiple items to `Bottom`, it just processes them in order. So whatever is bottom-most has to be placed in the DockPanel first with `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`, then the item above that should be added next, etc. Alternatively, you can dock an entire StackPanel to the bottom, and place all your controls that should be docked to the bottom of the screen in there.

Comment: yeah that works with combination of your both answer ! I can finally see the cat. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but with a custom made Image class which I only rendered drawings on by using the DrawingContext in the `protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)` function. I did not understood then, that I either needed to set the size of the image (set the Width and Height properties) or create a new image from the drawingContext and make it the Source of the image, in order to resize the actual image.

I got my answer from here: [Get images from DrawingGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267228/get-images-from-drawinggroup) and the way I solved it was by changing the properties every time I used the Render function of my image:

```
DrawingImage drawingImage = new DrawingImage(mBackingStore);
Width = drawingImage.Width;
Height = drawingImage.Height;
```